# Build error (version error ) when I deployed to circle-ci

Tags: reactjs, eslint, circleci

**situation**

- I'm facing a problem with that version error when I deployed to
  circle-ci

**I've tried**

- I did delete node_modules and packcage.lock.json and remove lint from package.json and reinstalled node manually but that could not have solved the problem. Rather than other problems occurred.

this is my [repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/cinema-app)

**Error**

```
        There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
        It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
        
        The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
        
          "eslint": "^6.6.0"
        
        Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
        However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:
        
          /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/eslint (version: 7.12.1) 
        
        Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
        
        If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to a .env file in your project.
        That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem.

This problem was I forgot to uninstall yarn.lock just uninstall the package-lock.json

**The solving way**

1.delete package-lock.json and yarn.lock

2.Uninstall npm and yarn

3.yarn remove eslint

4.install npm

5.yarn add -D eslint

6.git push